# Not able to call class function from URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess, url-rewriting, function-calls

I'm VERY new to CodeIgniter and am having trouble calling a function from within my default class.

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller 
{

public function index()
    {
    $this->welcome();
    }

public function welcome()
    {
    $this->load->view('view_welcome');      
    }
}
```

**htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pickme/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

```
# Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

At the moment it is calling this Main controller by default as i would expect.

e.g

```
localhost/sitename
AND
localhost/sitename/index.php
AND
localhost/sitename/index.php/main/index
(All have the same result)
```

So i was under the impression that

```
localhost/sitename/class/function/id
```

would be how htaccess would be working but im getting a 404 error when i try and access

```
localhost/sitename/main/welcome
```

Comment: have you tried http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the rewrite rule suggested in the user manual.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Im not an expert with apace rewrite module, but yours definately looks wrong. You wouldn't want your application and system folders to be accesible from a browser. The best practice is actually to keep it outsite your web root folder.

Furthermore i see no reason to call the welcome method from the index method, instrad of just keeping the logic in the index controller.

But your idea of:

```
hostname/folder/class/function/parameters
```

Is very true :)

And last but not least, you have probably forgot to leave index file in your config.php blank, which you will need to do if you want to remove index.php.

Good luck (:

**EDIT:**

Try using this in your htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And in your config.php remember to add a trailing slash.

With this it works here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jens.  All the .htaccess stuff was gained from the phpacademy tutorial that i was following:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMg-pqwaGaE

I know that at this point there is no reason to call the welcome() function but if i did access localhost/sitename/main/welcome i would expect to have the same result as localhost/sitename (which i am not getting)

Comment: Did you actually try with the htaccess i provided and did you remove "index.php" from the config.php file?

Comment: I'm getting the same result.  localhost/sitename/ works but localhost/sitename/main and localhost/sitename/main/welcome DO NOT

Comment: Im still not sure whether or not, you did leave the index file in config.php blank??? I've seen so often that people dont know about it or forget it, and that would make it fail.

Comment: Alright. Please check that your htaccess file does have a period in front and does not have another extension like txt. Windows might hide the file extension by default.

Comment: localhost/sitename/index.php/main/welcome. Also check that this does not work

Comment: The file is .htaccess with NO extension. 
 
localhost/sitename/index.php/main/welcome DOES work.

Comment: That means that the rewriting is being done at least. And i would've thought that could only mean the index file configuration wasn't done, but apparently not. If you upload your project, i will take a quick look.

Comment: What am i adding a trailing slash to?  I just tried adding it to the base_url - still no luck...

Comment: Well yes the base url, but the thing that made the difference was the htaccess. The one you had did not work for me, but the new one i provided did work.

Comment: Sure it could. If url rewrite is not turned on, it wouldnt work.

Comment: In your httpd.conf there should be a line starting with LoadModule and has something like mod_rewrite after that. If it's commented it's disabled and you just remove the comment.